# Python (+Django) : use @property in success_url KO . while using it with get_success_url is OK (class based view)

Tags: python-3.x, django, properties, django-class-based-views

I found a workaround for my issue but I need to know why the first above case doesn't work.

I need to pass a parameter (reman_pk) to my view but when I try :

```
class RepairCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    @property
    def reman_pk(self):
        return int(self.kwargs['reman_pk'])
    [...]
    success_url = reverse_lazy(
        'reman:update-reman', kwargs={'pk': reman_pk})
    [...]
```

... I got an error

**django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'update-reman' with keyword arguments '{'pk': <property object at 0x10c20bbd0>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['reman/update/(?P[0-9]+)/$']**

But when in the same class based view I use :

```
def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs != None:
            return reverse_lazy('reman:update-reman', kwargs={'pk': self.reman_pk})
```

... it's OK : an `int` is well passed in my URL.

I tried to pass `int(reman_pk)` in the first method ... not better.

I've already use `@property` in the past and always got a value (int/str) and not property object.

**EDIT (FULL views.py)**

`success_url = reverse_lazy...`is commented. I must use `def get_success_url( ...` instead. Otherwise I get the above mentioned error.

```
class RepairCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    @property
    def reman_pk(self):
        return int(self.kwargs['reman_pk'])

    # success_url = reverse_lazy(
    #     'reman:repairs-list', kwargs={'pk': reman_pk})

    success_message = "Nouvelle réparation créée"
    form_class = RepairCreateForm
    template_name = 'reman/repair_create_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(RepairCreateView, self).get_context_data(
            *args, **kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Nouveau Repair'
        context['pk'] = self.reman_pk
        return context

    def get_initial(self):
        reman = Reman.objects.get(pk=self.reman_pk)
        return {'reman': reman}

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('reman:repairs-list', kwargs={'pk': self.reman_pk})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to django, this is related to python in general. When you want to access a class property within the class you always have to call `self` before!

```py
class Tree:
    fruits = 5

    @property
    def leafes(self):
        return self.fruits * 5

    def show_tree(self):
        print(self.fruits)
        print(self.leafes)
        print(leafes)  # THIS LINE WOULD ERROR
```

### Edit after comment of OP

I don't know how to phrase this properly. Anyhow this keeps being a problem related to python and not to django. The reason is how classes work.

You probably know the `def __init__(self):` function. That is called when the class gets instanciated. **After** that function got called your class can use all the `self` attributes (class attributes). **But** class attributes like my `fruits = 5` **get assigned even before** that `def __init__(self)` method is called. So all your assignments directly inside the body of the class **do not have `self` yet**.

```py
class Tree:
    fruits = 5
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.twigs = 10
        self.weight = self.twigs + self.fruits  # THIS WORKS
```

```py
class Tree:
    fruits = 5
    weight = self.twigs + fruits  # THIS DOES NOT WORK
  
    def __init__(self):
        self.twigs = 10
```

Last example **does not work** because at the moment you want to assign `weight = self.twigs + fruits` your class's `__init__` function was not called yet. So you can not use `self` at that place.

Comment: Thanks @Tarquinius. Yes I knew that but my question was, why can't I use `success_url = reverse_lazy('reman:update-reman', kwargs={'pk': reman_pk})` directly inside the class and need to add a specific method as 'def get_success_url(self, **kwargs)`

Comment: Ok, maybe my edit helps you further.

Comment: Ok, I understand better the way that `__init__` works and that I can't call a property before `__init__` has done his job. BUT, once again, it doesn't seem that in my case I'm concerned by this point. Because, the way I call my `@property` seems OK because I got well the object (property) back. But why don't I get it's value instead of the full object ?

Comment: I need to see the entire view to process your question.